# How to find all system schemas in a given Vertex metadataStore?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Vertex ML Metadata publishes and maintains system-defined schemas for representing common types widely used in ML workflows. How can I find all the supported system schemas in my own Vertex MetadataStore.

Answer (score 0):

System defined schema are maintained by Vertex services and will also be updated when new schemas are added to the system. Those schemas are managed under namespace "system" and "google". To find all currently supported system defined schemas in a given store, one can follow the instructions listed in https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/ml-metadata/system-schemas#list_your_schemas.